# Django inner Join database Query

Tags: django, postgresql

Hello I've 3 models in my project and would like to do an inner join query on them.

```
class Experiment(models.Model):
    experiment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    experiment_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class DataFile(models.Model):
    file_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    experiment_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Analysis(models.Model):
    sample_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    file_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm using postgre and the query which I'm trying is

```
select experiment_name,ma.rt
FROM main_experiment me 
INNER JOIN main_datafile md 
ON me.experiment_id = md.experiment_id
INNER JOIN main_analysis ma
ON ma.file_id = md.file_id
```

I want to extract all the sample name name using the experiment id
I tried

```
Experiment.objects.filter(experiment_id__sample_name=18)
```

and many other combinations but I always get the below error.

Unsupported lookup ' ' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted.

Comment: Did you check? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984676/django-equivalent-for-sql-query-using-inner-join-clause

Comment: @giaco Yes I tried Analysis.objects.filter(sample_name__file_id=257), But it gives me the mentioned error

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use foreignkey? If your models look like;

```
class Experiment(models.Model):
    #experiment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # you don't need to add, django will do it for you.
    experiment_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class DataFile(models.Model):
    #file_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # you don't need to add, django will do it for you.
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    experiment = models.ForeignKey(Experiment, related_name="data_file")
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Analysis(models.Model):
    sample_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    data_file = models.ForeignKey(DataFile, related_name="analysis")
```

Then you can do:

```
Experiment.objects.filter(data_file__analysis__sample_name= 18)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, the database is already created and there is data in it, is there any easier way to do it without needing to modify the current table structure

Comment: @dexter: I think a tricky way to do it, actually if you change model structure with models.ForeignKey and just fake the migration, it should works fine. experiment_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True) becomes experiment_id = models.ForeignKey(Experiment, blank=True, related_name="data_file",null=True) and file_id should; file_id = models.ForeignKey(DataFile, related_name="analysis").

Comment: Or: you can always do: 
analysis = Analysis.objects.filter(sample_name= 18).values_list("file_id", flat=True)
datafiles = DataFile.objects.filter(file_id__in = analysis).values_list("experiment_id", flat= True)
experiments = Experiment.objects.filter(experiment_id__in = datafiles)